# How can I access the BrowserWindow JavaScript global from the main process in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want a menu, defined in the main process to call JavaScript code inside the current browser window in an [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) or [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) application.

Getting main process globals from the browser window is

```
const remote = require('remote')
const foo    = remote.getGlobal('foo')
```

What is the equivalent for the main process (AKA get the current window globals)? This is what I want to do in pseudocode

```
// JavaScript inside the main process
const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')
//...
// Inside the menu callback
let window    = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
let commander = window.global('commander') /// <---- Pseudocode!!!
commander.handleCommand('File.Save')
```

Comment: This works: `window.webContent.executeJavaScript("commander.handleCommand('File.Save')")`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/72ebb2c9fe676ada1356dc673f315584d8834f32/docs/api/remote.md#remote) is a reference to your comment about the webContents process in the API, in the "Note:" under remotes.

However, if you just want to trigger a function, you could also use the [webContents.send()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#webcontentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-) and [ipc(main process)](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/30d815e28f0bf0215da9e5a0e85de280a86b5cc9/docs/api/ipc-main-process.md#ipc-main-process) processes to trigger the appropriate code to run. Something like this...

```
// JavaScript inside the main process
const window = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

ipc.on('menuItem-selected', function(){
    let focusedWindow    = window.getFocusedWindow();
    focusedWindow.webContents.send('file-save');
});

// Inside the menu callback
require('ipc').on('file-save', function() {
  // File save function call here
});
```

---

For Electron version 0.35.0 and above, the ipc API changed to the following:

```
// In main process.
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// In renderer process (web page).
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

Comment: `require('ipc')` is now deprecated. Use `require('electron').ipcRenderer`.

Answer (score 0):

For electron version 11.x.x you can do this

```
// In renderer process

const { ipcRenderer } = window.require("electron");

ipcRenderer.on("your-event-here", () => {

    //hand your event here 
    
});


//In the main process

import { ipcMain } from "electron";

ipcMain.handle("handle-event-here", async (event, data) => {

  // write custom code here

});
```